# AWS EBS CSI Driver: Could not delete volume ID "vol-XXX": DeleteDisk could not delete volume: UnauthorizedOperation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, amazon-ebs, aws-ebs-csi-driver

- I'm running aws ebs csi driver inside aws eks 1.23 cluster via helm chart.
- I have PVCs provisioned with gp2 storage class
  PV is not being deleted once PVC is deleted.

### version of aws ebs csi driver

```bash
➜ helm search repo ebs                                
NAME                                    CHART VERSION   APP VERSION DESCRIPTION                                       
aws-ebs-csi-driver/aws-ebs-csi-driver   2.10.1          1.11.2      A Helm chart for AWS EBS CSI Driver
```

### PV tags

created aws volume has the following tags:

```ini
kubernetes.io/cluster/cluster-prod-eks  owned
Name    kubernetes-dynamic-pvc-07ee7aa2-5a7d-4f2b-af34-6fea3cda2fa8
kubernetes.io/created-for/pvc/name  teleport
kubernetes.io/created-for/pv/name   pvc-07ee7aa2-5a7d-4f2b-af34-6fea3cda2fa8
kubernetes.io/created-for/pvc/namespace teleport-cluster
```

### storage class

```bash
➜ kg sc gp2 -o yaml                             
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"storage.k8s.io/v1","kind":"StorageClass","metadata":{"annotations":{"storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class":"true"},"name":"gp2"},"parameters":{"fsType":"ext4","type":"gp2"},"provisioner":"kubernetes.io/aws-ebs","volumeBindingMode":"WaitForFirstConsumer"}
    storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
  creationTimestamp: "2022-05-31T04:31:24Z"
  name: gp2
  resourceVersion: "271"
  uid: ef10dad0-6a58-4251-a802-d14744bcde43
parameters:
  fsType: ext4
  type: gp2
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
reclaimPolicy: Delete
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

### behavior

once the pvc is deleted, the **ebs-csi-controller** is unable to delete the pv/volume and they all remain "active" inside AWS (not attached to anything) and inside **ebs-csi-controller** logs I see frequent repeating messages:

```bash
➜ klo -l app=ebs-csi-controller -c ebs-plugin
E0902 00:34:52.026908       1 driver.go:120] GRPC error: rpc error: code = Internal desc = Could not delete volume ID "vol-06f9e6132612684e6": DeleteDisk could not delete volume: UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded authorization failure message: XXXXX
    status code: 403, request id: ca6d72c5-c9f0-4b41-bcac-c92058b05aad

➜ decode_aws XXXXX

{
  "allowed": false,
  "explicitDeny": false,
  "matchedStatements": {
    "items": []
  },
  "failures": {
    "items": []
  },
  "context": {
    "principal": {
      "id": "AROAV5U3TKTQCOL2VXPJD:i-024e6c62a64f813a9",
      "arn": "arn:aws:sts::44444444444:assumed-role/prod-ops-v2-eks-node-group-20220629070052177800000004/i-024e6c62a64f813a9"
    },
    "action": "ec2:DeleteVolume",
    "resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:44444444444:volume/vol-0e7e820f437b74069",
    "conditions": {
      "items": [
        {
          "key": "ec2:ResourceTag/kubernetes.io/cluster/cluster-prod-eks",
          "values": {
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "owned"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "44444444444:Name",
          "values": {
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "kubernetes-dynamic-pvc-07ee7aa2-5a7d-4f2b-af34-6fea3cda2fa8"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "aws:Resource",
          "values": {
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "volume/vol-0e7e820f437b74069"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "aws:Account",
          "values": {
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "44444444444"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "ec2:AvailabilityZone",
          "values": {
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "us-east-1b"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "ec2:Encrypted",
          "values": {
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "false"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "ec2:ResourceTag/Name",
          "values": {
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "kubernetes-dynamic-pvc-07ee7aa2-5a7d-4f2b-af34-6fea3cda2fa8"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "ec2:VolumeType",
          "values": {
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "gp2"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "ec2:ResourceTag/kubernetes.io/created-for/pv/name",
          "values": {
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "pvc-07ee7aa2-5a7d-4f2b-af34-6fea3cda2fa8"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "aws:Region",
          "values": {
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "us-east-1"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "aws:Service",
          "values": {
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "ec2"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "ec2:VolumeID",
          "values": {
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "vol-0e7e820f437b74069"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "44444444444:kubernetes.io/created-for/pvc/namespace",
          "values": {
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "teleport-cluster"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "ec2:VolumeSize",
          "values": {
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "10"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "44444444444:kubernetes.io/created-for/pv/name",
          "values": {
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "pvc-07ee7aa2-5a7d-4f2b-af34-6fea3cda2fa8"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "ec2:ResourceTag/kubernetes.io/created-for/pvc/namespace",
          "values": {
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "teleport-cluster"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "aws:Type",
          "values": {
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "volume"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "ec2:VolumeIOPS",
          "values": {
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "100"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "ec2:ResourceTag/kubernetes.io/created-for/pvc/name",
          "values": {
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "teleport"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "ec2:Region",
          "values": {
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "us-east-1"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "aws:ARN",
          "values": {
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:44444444444:volume/vol-0e7e820f437b74069"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "44444444444:kubernetes.io/created-for/pvc/name",
          "values": {
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "teleport"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "44444444444:kubernetes.io/cluster/cluster-prod-eks",
          "values": {
            "items": [
              {
                "value": "owned"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

my instance **i-024e6c62a64f813a9** that runs the **ebs-csi-controller** pod has the managed AWS policy `AmazonEBSCSIDriverPolicy` attached to the IAM Role `arn:aws:sts::44444444444:assumed-role/prod-ops-v2-eks-node-group-20220629070052177800000004/i-024e6c62a64f813a9`

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateSnapshot",
                "ec2:AttachVolume",
                "ec2:DetachVolume",
                "ec2:ModifyVolume",
                "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeSnapshots",
                "ec2:DescribeTags",
                "ec2:DescribeVolumes",
                "ec2:DescribeVolumesModifications"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateTags"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:snapshot/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:CreateAction": [
                        "CreateVolume",
                        "CreateSnapshot"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DeleteTags"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:snapshot/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateVolume"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/ebs.csi.aws.com/cluster": "true"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateVolume"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/CSIVolumeName": "*"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateVolume"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/kubernetes.io/cluster/*": "owned"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DeleteVolume"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/ebs.csi.aws.com/cluster": "true"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DeleteVolume"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/CSIVolumeName": "*"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DeleteVolume"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/kubernetes.io/cluster/*": "owned"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DeleteSnapshot"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/CSIVolumeSnapshotName": "*"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DeleteSnapshot"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/ebs.csi.aws.com/cluster": "true"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

### Expectation

Since the volume is tagged with **kubernetes.io/cluster/cluster-prod-eks: owned** I expect it to be deleted automatically as the storageclass has `reclaimPolicy: Delete` but in reality I'm getting error message.

What am I doing wrong?

### cloudtrain entry

```json
{
    "eventVersion": "1.08",
    "userIdentity": {
        "type": "AssumedRole",
        "principalId": "AROAV5U3TKTQCOL2VXPJD:i-024e6c62a64f813a9",
        "arn": "arn:aws:sts::44444444444:assumed-role/prod-ops-v2-eks-node-group-20220629070052177800000004/i-024e6c62a64f813a9",
        "accountId": "44444444444",
        "accessKeyId": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
        "sessionContext": {
            "sessionIssuer": {
                "type": "Role",
                "principalId": "AROAV5U3TKTQCOL2VXPJD",
                "arn": "arn:aws:iam::44444444444:role/prod-ops-v2-eks-node-group-20220629070052177800000004",
                "accountId": "44444444444",
                "userName": "prod-ops-v2-eks-node-group-20220629070052177800000004"
            },
            "webIdFederationData": {},
            "attributes": {
                "creationDate": "2022-09-01T19:22:40Z",
                "mfaAuthenticated": "false"
            },
            "ec2RoleDelivery": "2.0"
        }
    },
    "eventTime": "2022-09-02T01:18:36Z",
    "eventSource": "ec2.amazonaws.com",
    "eventName": "DeleteVolume",
    "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
    "sourceIPAddress": "11.11.11.111",
    "userAgent": "aws-sdk-go/1.44.45 (go1.17.13; linux; amd64) exec-env/aws-ebs-csi-driver-v1.11.2",
    "errorCode": "Client.UnauthorizedOperation",
    "errorMessage": "You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded authorization failure message: XXXXX",
    "requestParameters": {
        "volumeId": "vol-06f9e6132612684e6"
    },
    "responseElements": null,
    "requestID": "461cafb4-00e6-4f70-a0de-2660517dd1fe",
    "eventID": "04a67446-0bd5-40f0-bfd5-3a8d5938f652",
    "readOnly": false,
    "eventType": "AwsApiCall",
    "managementEvent": true,
    "recipientAccountId": "44444444444",
    "eventCategory": "Management",
    "tlsDetails": {
        "tlsVersion": "TLSv1.2",
        "cipherSuite": "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256",
        "clientProvidedHostHeader": "ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
    }
}
```

Comment: Policy looks fine to me, but I would advise against allowing pods to assume the IAM role of the host node. Have you checked cloudtrail logs?

Comment: yes checked, it displays no more additional info. Same error: Client.UnauthorizedOperation

Comment: what is the actual command for decode_aws? (this looks to be an alias right?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**solution:**

Was to add 2 tags to the volume resources so the conditions of the managed policy **arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEBSCSIDriverPolicy** kicked in:

- CSIVolumeName = UNIQUE_NAME
- ebs.csi.aws.com/cluster = true

bash script to automate for many PVCs:

```bash
for vlm in $(aws ec2 describe-volumes --filters Name=tag:kubernetes.io/cluster/xxx-yyy-eks,Values=owned --filters Name=tag:Name,Values="kubernetes-dynamic-pvc*" --query "Volumes[*].VolumeId" --output text); do 
   CSIVolumeName=$(aws ec2 describe-volumes --volume-ids $vlm --query "Volumes[*].Tags[]" | jq -r '.[] | select(.Key=="Name").Value');
   echo $vlm,$CSIVolumeName
   aws ec2 create-tags --resources $vlm --tags Key=CSIVolumeName,Value=$CSIVolumeName
   aws ec2 create-tags --resources $vlm --tags Key=ebs.csi.aws.com/cluster,Value=true
done
```

Attach that policy to the IAM role used by the aws instance on which your csi controller is running:

```
➜ node=$(kubectl get nodes \
     $(kubectl get pods \
           -l app=ebs-csi-controller \
           -n kube-system \
           --no-headers \
           -o="custom-columns=NAME:.spec.nodeName") \
     -o="custom-columns=NAME:.spec.providerID" --no-headers | grep -o 'i-.*')

➜ aws ec2 describe-instances \
    --instance-ids $node --query "Reservations[0].Instances[0].IamInstanceProfile.Id"

AIPA6BMT6GMYXEPTKCHX1

➜ aws iam list-instance-profiles \
    --query "InstanceProfiles[?InstanceProfileId=='AIPA6BMT6GMYXEPTKCHX1'].Roles[]"

[
    {
        "Path": "/",
        "RoleName": "xxx-yyy-eks20210302004820371500000013",
        "RoleId": "AROA6BMT6GMY3HIGPUGQD",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::xx:role/xxx-yyy-eks20210302004820371500000013",
        "CreateDate": "2021-03-02T00:48:20+00:00",
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [
                {
                    "Sid": "EKSWorkerAssumeRole",
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Principal": {
                        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
                    },
                    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because `StringLike` only matches in values, not in keys:

```json
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DeleteVolume"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/kubernetes.io/cluster/*": "owned"
                }
            }
        },
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition_operators.html

> The **values** can include multi-character match wildcards (*) and single-character match wildcards (?) anywhere in the string.

So, in your case `kubernetes.io/cluster/cluster-prod-eks` != `kubernetes.io/cluster/*`. By adding other 2 Tags, you matched to other matchers having no '*' in keys.

Comment: wow, that is a major bug. This is a policy provided by AWS. And I now have hundreds of volumes that are not being deleted.